# Performing filter in album Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, filter

I have a difficulty to filter an album using https://graph.facebook.com/, I'm trying to filter an album by its id through the url.

My attempts:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?id=299487516834938&access_token=#####

As you can see, I'm trying to filter the album by its id, but I can not.

I wonder how I use the filter by url.

Comment: If you do not like the question, or find it very easy, please help or correct before giving negative post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want access to one specific album, you need to access it directly:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/299487516834938
```

...or if you want to get all photos in that album:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/299487516834938/photos
```

(of course with an Access Token)

See Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/album